# Is someone bound to the religion he is born into by birth?

Tags: philosophy, karma, birth

Is someone obligated to follow a certain religion that he/she is born into or does that person has the freedom to leave it based on Hinduism?

The reason I'm asking this question is a Hindu family I know have a mindset that *"if someone is born in a religion they are not allowed to follow another if even he/she wishes to as God wanted them to be born this way. If they started to follow another religion (not the one they are born into), they betray the family and the religion itself and are sinners. Even if someone left another religion for Hinduism??*

Is this true? Can someone provide me with some references from scriptures which say whether this statement is true or not?

My humble apologies if I've said something inconvenient but please provide me with some answers.